# How to echo last few of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I've seen an example for echoing the very last element in an array, but how do I echo the last 3 to 4 items in PHP?

I want to echo in REVERSE order, so the screen would show item 10, item 9, item 8 in an array of 10 items.  I will not know the number of items in the array.

Here's my progress so far, but I know I'll need a loop or something.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$comments = file_get_contents('comments.txt');
$array = explode("~",$comments);

for...

?????

echo $item;

?>
```

Comment: `$array = array_reverse($array)`

Comment: `sizeof` or `count` will give you the number of elements. You can access an element using its index. If you know the number of elements, it becomes trivial to count X from start or end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `array_reverse`

```
<?php
$a=[1,2,3,4,5];
$array = array_reverse($a);
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){//4 is the number of elements you wish to print.
 echo "{$array[$i]}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slice the first three off of the reversed array:

```
$result = array_slice(array_reverse($array), 0, 3);

foreach($result as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: This would make a nice function!

Answer (score 0):

I  think, you can reverse your array i.e. `$array`..`array_reverse()` function will be useful for this.

And once you have reversed `$array`...then you can run a loop on it and print the desired number of elements.